# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT] while running Android App on Intellij Genymotion Plug-in

Tags: android, intellij-idea, genymotion

I wanted to test my Android app on a Genymotion virtual machine through a Genymotion plugin on IntelliJ. I keep on getting this error message. 
`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]`
I get the same message when running my app in an actual Android device. I tried re-installing intellij but it did not work.

Here's my logcat BTW.

```
02-06 00:45:28.364      237-264/system_process E/PackageManager﹕ Package com.codeUP.juanderlab has mismatched uid: 10083 on disk, 10096 in settings
02-06 00:45:28.698      111-111/? E/installd﹕ dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.codeUP.juanderlab-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 65280
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-install IntelliJ. Just delete some of your applications in the GenyMotion emulator by going to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications

Or, just stop your GenyMotion emulator and start it again.